# setting and retrieving highscores of iOS app on Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to post highscores from my iOS app on Facebook. I've already read on the [Scores API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores) but it does explain to my understanding how exactly my highscore (say `int score` variable) will be linked programmatically from my code to Facebook. Also I followed the instructions below:

[image]

and was getting the following error.

[image]

I will really appreciate some help. Thanks.

**UPDATED:**

I am using the following code to update the score on Facebook:

```
    -(void)postScoreToFacebook:(int)currentScore
{
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"4356"], @"score",
                                  nil];
    NSLog(@"Fetching current score");
    // Get the score, and only send the updated score if it's highter
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/scores",  @"XXXXX"] parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (result && !error) {
            int nCurrentScore = [[[[result objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0]  objectForKey:@"score"] intValue];
            NSLog(@"Current score is %d", nCurrentScore);
            if (currentScore > nCurrentScore) {
                NSLog(@"Posting new score of %d", currentScore);
                [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/scores", @"XXXXX"] parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                    NSLog(@"Score posted");
                }];
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Existing score is higher - not posting new score");
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

I keep getting the following error when checking the score using the Graph API `/USER_ID/scores`

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph API documentation at  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the user ID of the user whose score you want to update, not the string `USER_ID`

Comment: I replaced the `USER_ID` string with the user ID and got the following error, `"error": {
    "message": "The global ID XXXX is not allowed. Please use the application specific ID instead.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2500`

Comment: Also, as I asked in the question, I would really like to know how the score variable in my code is linked programmatically to the facebook score. Currently, I haven't handled this.

Comment: Use the user ID the API gave you, not one you copied from somewhere else - user IDs are app-specific for apps created since April 30th - for your other question, it's not linked automatically, you use the scores API to tell Facebook what score to save, but it's not directly linked with anything in your app unless you manually keep it aligned